# How to obtain ASP.NET debugging path using reflection?

Tags: asp.net, debugging, reflection

I'm trying to load an assembly and instantiate a type contained on it using reflection.

The assembly is included in the references and is copied to the Bin folder after publishing, but when debugging, the assembly is not found.

I noticed that each assembly is deployed to a different temp folder for debug, something like: 

`C:\Users\Rafael\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
root\a8b5e5d3\720e0f4c\assembly\dl3\7c6d5cae\d096ebc2_d1c5c901`

This way, I cannot use the path of the running, the calling, or an assembly that contains a known type to build the path of the desired one.

Does anyone know how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

All those folders are added to the assembly search path, so you can say something like Assembly.Load("test.dll"), without supplying absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

Add folowing to *app.config*:

```
<system.web>
   <hostingEnvironment shadowCopyBinAssemblies="false" />
</system.web>
```

After that, DevServer will put everything in one folder and reflecting assemly would work.